# How can I change the directory holding the test files in ExtUtils::Makemaker?

Tags: perl, testing, makemaker

How can you change the default tests path in *Makefile.PL* from the default value *t/*.t*? There's an attribute mentioned in the documentation but it does not work. Anybody know how to that?

Comment: Which attribute did you found mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Makefile.PL:

```
WriteMakefile(
    test => { TESTS => 'tests/*.t'},
    ....
```

Will make `make test` run the tests scripts in `tests` instead of `t`.

Comment: This seems to work with the latest Makemaker, but it was broken for a while. That breakage led me to write Test::Manifest.

Comment: I thought that was because of the automatic sorting.

Comment: I actually saw it in the documentation. But I didn't try it, I was a little confuse about it ( capital attributes and lowercase attributes). It's a bit confusing.

Comment: It is! Just don't think too much about it and give it a try.

Comment: @Schwern: a long time ago I used TESTS to set the order I wanted. You were working on something that broke that, I asked you about it, and you said "Don't do that". So I came up with another way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Manni's suggestion allows you to have the glob pattern that MakeMaker will use in the test targets, but that's still rather limited. I wrote [Test::Manifest](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Manifest) so that I could override those portions to do exactly what I needed to do. Even if you don't want to do the same thing that  Test::Manifest does, you can look at the source to see what I did.

Comment: Awesome! Why didn't I know about that little nugget?